# Using PouchDB or (CouchDB) VS using JSON file

Tags: json, database, nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a question regarding performance:

I have a rather static JSON file that is ~25000 lines long. This file is used to query on and extract some values.

I am wondering what would grant the **highest performance**:

- Read this file and keep in memory, traverse through the file to query for results.

Or

- Load the file as documents into a PouchDB database and create views for the required queries.

This is an example of how the file would look like:

```
    [
    {
        "ATL1": "AD", 
        "ATL2": "Server", 
        "ATL3": "Cloud 1", 
        "ATT": "SSS Server", 
        "Base1": "Per Image", 
        "TAG": 147897, 
        "LID": "43834", 
        "R1": "Intel", 
        "R2": "Infra", 
        "R3": "", 
        "BL1": "Distributed", 
    }, 
    {
        "ATL1": "AD", 
        "ATL2": "Server", 
        "ATL3": "Cloud 2", 
        "ATT": "SSS Server", 
        "Base1": "Per Image", 
        "TAG": 098765, 
        "LID": "45334", 
        "R1": "Intel", 
        "R2": "Infra", 
        "R3": "", 
        "BL1": "Distributed", 
    }, 
    {
        "ATL1": "AD", 
        "ATL2": "Server", 
        "ATL3": "System Services", 
        "ATT": "SSS Server", 
        "Base1": "Per CPU", 
        "TAG": 098765, 
        "LID": "42534", 
        "R1": "UNIX", 
        "R2": "Infra", 
        "R3": "XXXX", 
        "BL1": "Distributed", 
    },

    ...

    ]
```

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it? In theory, PouchDB should be faster since it uses indexes.

Comment: The _only_ way to answer this, is to benchmark.

Comment: i am having a json file around 300MB and having 1000000 rows. i have to run a search query on it. Not sure what to do and how to do. Any suggestion .??